# Prestashop run script after purchase of a precise item

Tags: prestashop-1.6

As title, I would like to run a script after a precise item has been purchased.
I searched on web to find some clue on how to start it, but nothing.
Thanks a lot

Riccardo

Answer (score 1):

You could [create a custom module](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module) that is using the `actionValidateOrder` hook which is called after the order was created. In the hook you could loop through the ordered products to check whether the specific product was purchased and execute a given code block if the condition is met.

Comment: Ok, I will study this "hook" thing. Sounds interesting! Thanks a lot!